# Implement Simple linear regression for predicting a response using a single feature using python

Tags: python, regression, linear-regression, prediction

[using this data as refrance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdqzR.png)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  
def estimate_coef(x, y):
    # number of observations/points
    n = np.size(x)
  
    # mean of x and y vector
    m_x = np.mean(x)
    m_y = np.mean(y)
  
    # calculating cross-deviation and deviation about x
    SS_xy = np.sum(y*x) - n*m_y*m_x
    SS_xx = np.sum(x*x) - n*m_x*m_x
  
    # calculating regression coefficients
    b_1 = SS_xy / SS_xx
    b_0 = m_y - b_1*m_x
  
    return (b_0, b_1)
  
def plot_regression_line(x, y, b):
    # plotting the actual points as scatter plot
    plt.scatter(x, y, color = "m",
               marker = "o", s = 30)
  
    # predicted response vector
    y_pred = b[0] + b[1]*x
  
    # plotting the regression line
    plt.plot(x, y_pred, color = "g")
  
    # putting labels
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.ylabel('y')
  
    # function to show plot
    plt.show()
  
def main():
    # observations / data
    x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
    y = np.array([1, 3, 2, 5, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10, 12])
  
    # estimating coefficients
    b = estimate_coef(x, y)
    print("Estimated coefficients:\nb_0 = {}  \
          \nb_1 = {}".format(b[0], b[1]))
  
    # plotting regression line
    plot_regression_line(x, y, b)
  
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Is above code correct and if not what should i do beacuse its showing error on google colab !!!
for output the the result shoul be a ploted graph
as shown in the following picture
[the output should be similar to this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0RDP.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think your primary question is about the error you are getting: could you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74441304/edit) the question and add the full error traceback?

Answer (score 0):

I replicate your code on my machine and it works perfectly, there is no bug in your code.

Library and its version that installed in my colab

```
Python     : 3.7.15
Numpy      : 1.21.6
Matplotlib : 3.2.2
```

You can also restart runtime it may solve your problem

click on Runtime

Select Restart runtime and then click on Run all